# Is there a difference between Python on Desktops and Python on ARM?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, arm, cpython

Situation: I am writing Python code on my laptop, to be used on an ARM device

Problem: When imported into an ARM device, there are some Python modules that cannot be found (basic ones like `sys` and `time`)

Question 1: Is this supposed to happen? As in some modules in the desktop version of Python are not available on ARM devices? If so, why?

Question 2: Are there an workarounds in regards to this problem? (like importing the files from the desktop to the ARM device, etc)

Comment: What ARM device is it? I find it hard to believe that sys is unavailable. And no, you cannot copy it from somewhere else. sys.path, sys.maxint etc are system specific.

Comment: I see. I am on Parallella. I tried reinstalling Python but it is still not 'appearing'

Comment: The Python modules are under `/usr/lib/python2.7/` right? There are only modules in this directory if I am not mistaken?

Comment: As Parallella's ePython has some issues with importing Python modules, I have copied all Python modules into the ePython directory (it works, but the issues are as above). So if I have missed out any directories that may explain why there is no `sys` module

Comment: I have no idea what Parallella or epython is, but this sounds like the proper installation procedure was not followed. Does parallella have a package management system, and did you use it?

Comment: Parallella's OS is based on Ubuntu, so `apt-get`. the command was `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python`

Comment: You can ask the vendor for help on their forum. Alternatively you can try to compile python from source, but that should not be necessary.